# What means "jungle`s creep" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

> In the near distance, hulking concrete bunkers, ugly and indifferent, held back the **jungle’s creep**.

Jungle as a forest or rather jungle as a mess/muddle? What do you think?

Comment: How should we know without context? Based on what you write, both are possible.

Comment: Jungle as a living, growing thing that would normally be slowly expanding to cover and eventually engulf the bunkers and whatever they protect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always show the link, in order to spare our wasting time.

> [Jet:](https://books.google.ca/books?id=6ynkAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT7&dq=%22%20hulking%20concrete%20bunkers,%20ugly%20and%20indifferent%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zZMmVZTaOY21sATdmYLAAg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22%20hulking%20concrete%20bunkers%2C%20ugly%20and%20indifferent%22&f=false) - Volume 1 Russell Blake
>
> In the near distance, hulking concrete bunkers, ugly and indifferent,
>   held back the **jungle's creep**.

It means the bunkers **stop the advancement** of the jungle (of any nature) that seems to exist around the city.

Comment: I have one more question then: Is the "bunker" in that sentence that "military thing" or something different? Thanks.